# Kusto when table was created

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table `11111111_1111_1111_1111_111111111111` in Kusto and I want to know when that table was created.

I figured this information will in the [show table details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/show-table-details-command) command:

```
.show table 11111111_1111_1111_1111_111111111111 details
```

But I don't see it there.

Where can I find when this table was created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run

```
.show journal | where EntityName == "11111111_1111_1111_1111_111111111111"
```

There you will see all management actions taken on that table, as far as the built-in journal goes.